# Why string interned but has different references?

Tags: c#, string, referenceequals

```
string s1 = "abc";
string s2 = "ab";
string s3 = s2 + "c";

Console.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(s3));           // abc
Console.WriteLine(String.ReferenceEquals(s1, s3));  // False
```

I just cannot understand why s3 interned, but `ReferenceEquals` was False.

Dose they have two copies in intern pool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because while the value of that string is indeed interned (because of the literal "abc"), it is not the same instance as the interned string, rather an instance generated by the + operator

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz you should make this an answer, was going to tell that but you were faster and more precise

Comment: Moreover, `Console.WriteLine(String.ReferenceEquals(s1, string.IsInterned(s3)));` should return true

Comment: Writing `String.ReferenceEquals` is confusing because the `static` method is in `System.Object`. So use either `ReferenceEquals` by itself (since the `class` or `struct` you are inside inherits `System.Object` ultimately) or use `object.ReferenceEquals` if you feel like emphasizing where that method is declared (or in the evil case where another user-defined `ReferenceEquals` method hides the one on `object`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically three different situations possible when `string.IsInterned` is invoked. To illustrate, here is a test method:

```
static void MyInternCheck(string str)
{
  var test = string.IsInterned(str);

  if ((object)test == (object)str)
    Console.WriteLine("Yes, your string instance is in the intern pool");
  else if (test == str)
    Console.WriteLine("An instance with the same value exists in the intern pool, but you have a different instance with that value");
  else if (test == null)
    Console.WriteLine("No instance with that value exists in the intern pool");
  else
    throw new Exception("Unexpected intern pool answer");
}
```

You can "hit" all three situations with this code:

```
static void Main()
{
  string x = "0";
  MyInternCheck(x);
  string y = (0).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  MyInternCheck(y);
  string z = (1).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  MyInternCheck(z);
}
```

Output:

```
Yes, your string instance is in the intern pool
An instance with the same value exists in the intern pool, but you have a different instance with that value
No instance with that value exists in the intern pool
```

Since the literal `"0"` is mentioned in the program text, a string instance with value `"0"` will exist in the intern pool. The variable `x` is a reference to that instance.

The variable `y` has the same *value* as `x`, but that is not computed until run-time (the C# compiler makes no guesses as to what `int.ToString(IFormatProvider)` could be returning). As a consequence, `y` is another instance than is `x`.

The variable `z` has a value that is not found in the intern pool.

Answer (score 6):

They are separate references. The string `"abc"` is interned because it is a literal string.

The expression `s2 + "c"` is compiled to `string.Concat(s2, "c")`.. which results in a new (and separate) string reference.

Comment: thanks, can you tell IsInterned() more details? That's makes me confused.

Comment: @LeiKan If the intern pool holds *some* string with the same *value* as `s3` then `string.IsInterned(s3)` returns the string from the intern pool. That is not necessarily the same instance as `s3`. So, as said in a comment to your question, `ReferenceEquals(s3, string.IsInterned(s3))`, or equivalently `(object)s3 == (object)string.IsInterned(s3)` can be false even when `IsInterned` does return an instance.

Answer (score 3):

This is because while the value of that string is indeed interned (because of the literal "abc"), it is not the same instance as the interned string, rather an instance generated by the + operator.

```
String.ReferenceEquals(s1, string.IsInterned(s3));
```

would return true

Comment: thanks, IsInterned() makes me confused. The output "abc" tells me it was interned, but you tell me it dosen't.

Comment: The [IsInterned method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the interned **instance** for a **value** (or null, if that string is not interned). Now, while using string literal will always return an interned **instance**, other operations won't necessarily do that, even if there is an interned **instance** for that **value**.